# find all lines with specific phrase in specific commit

Tags: linux, git, command-line

Lets assume I have a commit with a known hash, and the commit touches 1000 files of 5000 files of the project.

Among some of those files there was added the log message `LOG_WARNING(...);`, lets say 500 times. Which I want to replace by `LOG_INFO(...);`.

- I don't want to replace all `LOG_WARNING(...);` in the project (lets say it has 10000 of them), just ones, related to the specified commit.
- I'm ready to walk over each of 500 lines I have to modify, but I'm trying to avoid walking over 10000 existing log-lines in the codebase.

What is the best way (practice) to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did help to me:

1. `git diff (...) > patchfile` -- extract all changes of current commit to a patchfile
2. edit `patchfile` -- using any editing tool & script, but in the `patchfile` I had to deal with only `LOG_WARNING` of specified commit.
3. `git reset --hard` -- to get rid of the commit I'm going to modify
4. `git apply patchfile` -- applies "patch", containing exactly my commit, but with replacement I wanted to.

It does the job. And relatively quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it that way:

```
git show --name-only <commit> | xargs sed -i 's/LOG_WARNING/LOG_INFO/'
```

The `git` command give the filenames part of the commit.
`xargs` provides these files to `sed` which replaces the wanted pattern.

Comment: thx, its a nice way to filter out files, not touched by current commit. But if files, touched by current commit, contain `LOG_WARNING` of previous commits, `sed` will also replace them. Its important to replace just lines related to specified commit.

Comment: I think you need to parse the output of `git show <commit>` instead of `git show --name-only <commit>`